# Symfony2 Constraint Class not found

Tags: symfony, capistrano, capifony

Everything is ok in my dev environment on my local machine. However, on my new staging server, I get an error on my registration page only (as far as I can see):

> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\notNull' not found in /var/www/sf-ysu/shared/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Validator/Mapping/Loader/AbstractLoader.php on line 63

I use [capifony](http://capifony.org/) for deployment, which means my vendor directory is symlinked to another location. This **might** have something to do with it, but I'm not sure.

Does anyone have clue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you have Windows on your local machine and Windows is case insensitive. Make sure you use the `NotNull` constraint — not `notNull`.