# NotBlank not found in vendor?

Tags: validation, symfony, fatal-error

when i put my site on the server(witout ssh), i've got this:

```
FatalErrorException: Error: Class 'Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Notblank'
    not found in ../public_html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Validator/Mapping/Loader/AbstractLoader.php line 64
```

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14576590/notblank-not-found-in-symfony2) posted before, but I do not know where should I put my USE statement cause I use a validation.yml file separately.

I am so frastrating cause I can not use ssh in the server, so I have to solve problems locally and upload files separately.

Anyway, any help will be appreciated! THX!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a typo in your `use` statement. It should be:

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\NotBlank;
```

Comment: I just found the answer, my bad, cause I should post the validation.yml file out, I put "Notblank" instead of "NotBlank", it is case sensitive. So I dont need a statment. Any way thx @FyodorX!

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12249406/symfony2-constraint-class-not-found?rq=1), my mistakes:
1. It is case sensitive, I used "Notblack" instead of "NotBlank". (Damn, how should I know!)
2. I should post the code of validation.yml. Cause it not about the     Use statement.

Also, thx @FyodorX for answering in light speed.